# printf() is printing the wrong value

Tags: c, printf, arithmetic-expressions

This is my full code, and its printing random negative values each time I run it not sure what is wrong.
using Ubuntu to run and "gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

unsigned int x = 10;
unsigned int y = 16;
unsigned int p = x + y;

printf("%d\n", &p);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` is not `scanf`.

Comment: Why did you write `&p`?  Were you thinking of `scanf`?  In this case, you're passing `p`'s value to `printf`, so you don't want the `&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing the address of `p`. You need to pass the value.

```
printf("%d\n", p);
```

As you have it, your code is printing the address of `p`, whatever that happens to be.

In addition, since you are using `unsigned int`, you probably want to use the *%u* formatter insted of *%d*.